# Enabling tracing at a single processor

Tags: apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel in combination with Hawt.io administration console. I can enable tracing at route level, but I would need to enable tracing at a single processor level.

Is it possible in Apache Camel to enable tracing at a single processor? How ?

Comment: what do you mean by tracing? Is it the JMX statiscs, eg number of messages, or do you want to capture the message payload, or what?

Comment: I need to capture the payload and the header.

Answer (score 1):

Tracing is by default for an entire route, so you cannot say you only want to trace a specific processor.

You can however use interceptors or other ways to do your own tracing and only capture that information for one processor.

- http://camel.apache.org/intercept

But the out of the box tracing functionality is per route.

Comment: Let's say we have a choice processor, and we want to be able dynamically to start intercepting messages that take the "otherwise" branch. How would you suggest implementing it?